# adding multiple security group for lambda using cdk

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Function.html) you can pass the multiple security groups using `security_groups` as a list inside  `aws_cdk.aws_lambda.Function` then it should simply worl so, I have initialized

```
sg_names = ['sg-a', 'sg-b', 'sg-c', 'sg-d']
```

now when I try to call, `lambda. Function` like below:

```
Function(self, 'lambda_a',                                                     
        code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambdas'),
        handler='lambda_a.handler',
        function_name='lambda_a',
        runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
         role=lambda_role,
         vpc=vpc,
        security_groups=sg_names,
         timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
        )
```

Now it throws me error:

```
Expected object reference, got "sg-a"
```

it seems I should get the objects instead of the values.
So, maybe i think I need to call  `SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id`, but I don't see how to add multiple groups to this call.
Is there any suggestion how to add multiple security groups to lambda?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code, I am a beginner in python, please adjust if there is some mistake :)

```
def security_group(id):
   return SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, id, id)

sg_names = ['sg-a', 'sg-b', 'sg-c', 'sg-d']  
security_groups = map(security_group, sg_names)
```

Comment: Great, If it helped you acceptance of the answer and upvote will be appreciated 

Comment: yes, as you mentioned there is a mistake, but certainly, this will help someone in the right direction towards the solution. so upvoted ;-)